# How to query and append a list of users emails linked with a manytomany relation to other Model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

First please take a look on the data structure.
there are Three models

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.OneToOneField(
        Group, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    partner = models.ManyToManyField(
        Partner, blank=True)

class Quote(models.Model):
    partner = models.ManyToManyField(
        Partner, blank=True, related_name='quote_partners')
```

There can be multiple partners inside the Quote and CustomUser partner field.
I want to make a list of users email who are linked with Partner inside the partner field set in the quote model.
This is how I'm doing;

```
    quote = Quote.objects.get(id=id)
    partners = quote.partner.all()
    for partner in partners:
        recipient_list = []
        for user in CustomUser.objects.filter(groups__partner=partner):
            recipient_list.append(user.email)
```

Currently quote object has 3 partners and collectively 4 users linked to these partners then there should be 4 emails in the the `recipient_list`, But this returning empty array []. Please highlight what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(groups__partner__quote_partners__id=id)
```

This looks for `CustomUser`s linked to a `Group` linked to a `Partner` linked to a `Quote` with the given `id`.

You can query with:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(partner__quote_partners__id=id)
```

To look for `CustomUser`s that have a related `Partner` that has a related `Quote` with `id` as primary key.

Comment: But its not returning the correct data , it is still an empty array

Comment: @atropabelladona: note that we here consider `Partner`s that have at least one `Group` in common, as your code was doing. This is something else as the `partner`s of the `CustomUser`.

Comment: @atropabelladona: are you sure that for the given `id` of the `Quote`, there ia `CustomUser` that has a `Partner` in common for which there is a `Group` in common?

Comment: Yes 3 Partners , Each Partner is connected to distinct Group

Comment: Is there a problem in the loop ?

Comment: @atropabelladona: you reset the list each time per `partner`: the `recipient_list = []`, but probably the issue is still that there are no `Group`s in common: or the partners are not linked to groups, or these groups do not have `CustomUser`s.

Comment: There shouldnt be group in Common they are linked with OneToOneField with Partners

Comment: @atropabelladona: yes but these groups do not per se contain any `CustomUser`s.

Comment: Can we make a logic with Partner CustomUser and Quote Model , Excluding Groups ?

Comment: @atropabelladona: yes, see edit.